# How to find a field such that it is isomorphic to the set of formal fractions and power series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Give examples of fields $F$ such that:

1. $F$ is isomorphic to $F(t)$
2. $F$ is isomorphic to $F((t))$
3. $F(t)$ is isomorphic to $F((t))$.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Any ideas?

Comment: I would say that if the field in (a) was a prime subfield then there exists an isomorphic mapping since the field F consists of all elements that could be expressed as ab^-1. I really am not sure about the others though. Wasn't really taught the subject that well

Comment: Well, you have to be careful here also. $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ has just 2 elements, but $[\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}](t)$ has many, such as $t^n$ for each $n$.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? The real number set should be sufficient right ?

Comment: Well, if $F$ is a field, $F[t]$ is an integral domain and so a subset of $F(t)$. But $F[t]$ is "huge" compared to $F$ as it contains all polynomials in $F$. So for instance, $t, t^2, t^3, ...$. There probably is a simple example of such a field, but I can't really think of one at the moment. I'm interested to see what some of the experienced mathematicians on this site say.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Start from any field, say the rationals. Construct the field $F$ of all rational functions in the countably infinite set of "indeterminates" $t_1,t_2,t_3,\dots$.

Now add a new indeterminate, which we call $t_0$ instead of $t$. There is a straighforward to describe isomorphism from $F(t_0)$ to $F$. The idea is the same as [Hilbert's infinite hotel.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel)

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is f(to, t1, t2,...) and why would you need to map it to ti+1. All I know about F(t) and F((t)) is that F(t) is the set of formal functions and f((t)) is the field of Laurent series. I really don't know much beyond fields about abstract algebra. This is in a linear algebra class btw.

Comment: Isnt F(t) a fraction of one variable thiugh? You can't just assert that the isomorphism is the identity mapping? For c would we just state the morphism as multiplying the rational function by the polynomial in the denominator to establish a power series? Is this more abstract or linear algebra btw?

Comment: Isn't the fraction in terms of one variable though

Comment: The element of $F(t)$ is a rational function in one variable with coefficients in $F$. But to get an example where $F$ is isomorphic to $F(t)$, I made $F$ itself a field of rational functions. So the **coefficients** are rational functions of $t_1,t_2,\dots$. This makes $F(t)$ a collection of rational functions in many variables. The system gets upset by long comment strings, so I will delete most of mine. Suggest you do the same. That will leave room for any other questions you may have.

Comment: Thanks. How would this work in the case of c. I can see a similar approach to the second part.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have been extremely busy. The same basic strategy should work. start with say $\mathbb{Q}$, add a countable number of indeterminates $s_1,s_2,s_3,\dots$. Then add the formal power series in another countable number of indeterminates $t_1,t_2,\dots$, close up under field operations. That's your $F$. I am surprised at this in basically a linear algebra book, would have thought they would want a vector space over some base field like $\mathbb{Q}$, not a field. Same strategy works, but is somewhat simpler.

Comment: thanks a lot one last thing. how would you prove Q[sqrt 2, sqrt3] is a field. Like proving that a multiplicative inverse exists?